# How to code a subclassed QTextEdit to cause a slot call on a "enter" key press?

Tags: c++, qt

How to code a subclassed QTextEdit to cause a "slot" call on a "enter" key press?

```
//mainwindow.cpp
myTextEdit *mytext = new myTextEdit(this);
mytext->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(10,20), QSize(100,50)));
connect(mytext, SIGNAL(myReturn()), this, SLOT(handleText()));
```

---

```
    //subclassed QTextEdit
void myTextEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    QString qstr = ::myTextEdit::toPlainText();

    if(e->key() == 16777220){ //enter key
        qstr = qstr + "\r\n>> ";
        //now cause an event like a QPushButton "released()" event to cause a "slot" call 
    }else{
        qstr = qstr + e->key();
    }
    ::myTextEdit::setText(qstr);
}
```

Comment: when I place code in above, not sure why the tab-margins are lost?

Comment: Maybe your margins can be lost because your'e doing toPlainText()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//header

```
signals:
    void OnEnter;
```

---

```
void myTextEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
    {
        QString qstr = ::myTextEdit::toPlainText();

        if(e->key() == 16777220){ //enter key
            qstr = qstr + "\r\n>> ";
            //now cause an event like a QPushButton "released()" event to cause a "slot" call 
            emit OnEnter(); //creates the emit signal to call a slot
        }else{
            qstr = qstr + e->key();
        }
        ::myTextEdit::setText(qstr);
    }
```

---

setup slots like QPushButton